# How do i create an await expression using recast/esprima

Tags: javascript, esprima

I have a js function

```
export const cleanUp = async () => {
    await User.destroy({ where: {} });
};
```

I am trying to  insert a line below `await User.destroy({ where: {} })` using

```
recast.parse(`await ${module}.destroy({ where: {} });`);
```

But I keep. getting `Unexpected Identifier` because esprima expects an async declaration. How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

esprima claims "Full support for ECMAScript 2016 (ECMA-262 7th Edition)" while "await" initial definition was in "ECMAScript 2017 (ECMA-262)"

I think this can be the problem.

http://esprima.org/  (Features paragraph)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Specifications